# How do calculators handle floating point errors?

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I am writing a calculator interface in Python using Tkinter. I am aware of the floating point precision issues that can arise in computers, but I have never had to deal with them directly.

In my calculator for example, I am multiplying two floats together, say 3.2 and 3.0. Instead of resulting in 9.6, however, I get 9.60000000000001 (or something). Normally, I would just round this number. However, under circumstances where I would need that extra precision, I wish to keep it. What is the standard practice for dealing with this issue?

Comment: You can use `decimal.Decimal`.

Comment: How do you suggest using that? When I pass the operation into that constructor, I get even more decimal places

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html for some important limitations of floating point numbers.

Comment: Python defines a constant for the number of digits you can safely use but I'm having a hard time finding it. In any case you'll have to choose a number of digits and round for display, otherwise what will you do with `1/3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, under circumstances where I would need that extra precision, I wish to keep it.

Your precision needs exceed what is readily available with standard binary floating point.

Use decimal or use higher precision binary math to reduce the occurrence of the perceived imprecision.

> What is the standard practice for dealing with this issue?

Common calculators always use more internal precision (decimal or not) than they show to avoid such floating point artifacts.

I recommend internal math that is at least 2-3 decimal places (8-10 bits) more than the significant maximum number of digits displayed.